# Sending Image from raspberrypi (python) to a webserver backend (php) using HTTP POST method

Tags: python, php, post, upload, raspberry-pi

Apologies in advance, I am only a beginner in this field

I'm trying to send a picture to a server... 
The server is PHP backend and the device is raspberry pi with linux OS using python language...

I researched a lot and tried a lot of codes for the said task

**The server side php script is**

```
<?php
    //if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //echo "Success";
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        print_r($file);
        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $filetmpname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileerror = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];

        $fileExt = explode('.', $file_name);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

        //$allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png', 'pdf','docx');
        //if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
            if ($fileerror === 0) {
                if ($filesize <1000000) {
                    $filenewname = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                    $fileDestination = 'pictures/'.$file_name;
                    move_uploaded_file($filetmpname, $fileDestination);
                    header("Location: upload_test.php?success");
                }else{
                    echo "File size too big!";
                }
            }else{
                echo "Error while uploading your file!";
            }
        //}
    //}
?>
```

it seems to be working finely when I use the submit button to send a picture from another php webpage.
(the lines commented in above code is because later on, I wanted to get the image without a submit button, that submit was only for getting the image from another php webpage)

**But** I want to sent image from Raspberry pi, so i found multiple codes for that,

```
import requests
import os
path_img='/home/pi/im.jpg'
url = 'http://*******.msahosting.net/pictures/'
#url = "http://*******.msahosting.net/upload.php" #tried both url
with open(path_img, 'rb') as img:
  name_img= os.path.basename(path_img)
  files= {'file': (name_img,img,'multipart/form-data',{'Expires': '0'}) }
  with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(url,files=files,data={'dir':'/pictures/'})
    print(r.status_code)
```

AND

```
import requests
url='http://*******.msahosting.net/pictures/'
#url = 'http://*******.msahosting.net/upload.php' #tried both
data = {'submit':'submit','upload':''}
files = {'file':('im.jpg', open('/home/pi/im.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
print(r)
```

**AND**

```
import requests
url = "http://*******.msahosting.net/upload.php"

files = {'files': open('/home/pi/im.jpg', 'rb')}
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data"
#    'accept': "application/json",
#    'apikey': "API0KEY0"
    }
response = requests.post(url, data=files, headers=headers)

print(response)
```

BUT none of them are working
they all return error code 200 which indicates no error, 
although when I check response.text I get something like this in my linux terminal window

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

but since here I'm not using any browser, I'm trying to upload image from my raspberry pi.

so apart from that, the error code is 200 but there's no file uploaded in the server directory

I tried changing 'file' to 'image'...
changing the directory url...
and many stuff since yesterday morning but no luck...

can anyone help me figure out the issue or right or better way to do the said task?

Thank you for reading...

*Best Regards*